# Как остановить тест в pytest?

Tags: python-3.x, сокет, юнит-тесты

Тест выглядит так

```
def test_status():
assert status() == 0
```

Тестируется сервер с ожиданием запроса

```
conn, addr = tcp_socket.accept()
```

А хотелось бы сразу узнать статус теста если     `assert status() != 0`
Так вот.Как можно остановить тест при отрицательном результате?

Comment: вопрос не ясен. Вы имеете в виду, что у вас несколько тестов и вы хотите выполнять дальнейшие тесты только если `test_status()` завершился успешно или что-то другое?

Comment: Нет, у меня один тест, нужно выдать результат если он завершился успешно/неуспешно сразу после выдачи этого результата

Comment: Яснее не стало: вы говорите  тест один и он завершился. Что вы остановить тогда хотите?